# Fix footer to bottom of Wordpress page

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

I'm aware there are many threads and answers for this, but I am not familiar whatsoever with CSS and struggle to understand where to implement the code.

I'm trying to get the footer to stay at the bottom of the page, for example on this page you can see the social icons are higher. https://www.timadams.ca/account/

I'm using Jackson theme, which is a child of Blockbase. Trying the additional CSS box doesn't have any effect, and I suspect this is because the parent theme is preventing it.

Does anyone have any ideas in which module I can add some code to make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: What CSS did you try? Are you sure you were targeting the correct elements? The additional CSS on a Child Theme is the correct place to put your code. That said, looking at your site, I'm the problem is everything is wrapped in a div with the class `wp-site-blocks` - including the footer. You could try adding `position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;` to your `.site-footer-container`, but that may cover your content if it gets longer.

Comment: I'm not sure which file I actually need to edit to make the correct change. Can you see where the .site-footer-container is located?

Comment: Add this to your Custom CSS box `.site-footer-container { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }` and see what happens. Beyond that, unless we had access to your files, we probably can't help much. Every theme is different.

Comment: Ok, interesting. That actually made it stick to the bottom, but floating as you first said.

Comment: The other way you could potentially do this, so the footer is at the bottom on short content pages, but not overlapping on longer pages, is to try this CSS in your custom CSS `.wp-site-blocks { min-height: 100vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;} .site-footer-container { margin-top: auto }` The `margin-top: auto` might already be set, so you probably don't need that, but that's worth a shot. Basically you are setting the entire container to be *at least* the height of the browser window - won't affect longer pages.